# Implementing local storage in a dynamic chart - chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, local-storage

I am trying to make a cost chart for my school project that measures planned and actual cost of projects. I got local storage working in a normal bar chart thanks to another post on here but can't get it working on this chart as it requires two datasets.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>LS&INPUTS - Colum</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="card">
    <p class="chart-heading">Job progress</p>

    <div class="container">
      
      <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>

        <div class="inputs-container">
          <div class="input-title">
            <p>Job</p>
            <p>Job progress(%)</p>
          </div>
              <!-- Input 1 -->
              <div class="inputfield">
                <input class="labelinput" type="text" id="input1text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" maxlength="10">
                <input class="plannedcost" type="number" id="plannedinput1" onchange ="updatePC()">
                <input class="actualcost" type="number" id="actualinput1" onchange ="updateAC()">
              </div>
              
              <!-- Input 2 -->
              <div class="inputfield">
                <input class="labelinput" type="text" id="input2text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" maxlength="10">
                <input class="plannedcost" type="number" id="plannedinput2" onchange="updatePC()">
                <input class="actualcost" type="number" id="actualinput2" onchange ="updateAC()">
              </div>

              <!-- Input 3 -->
              <div class="inputfield">
                <input class="labelinput" type="text" id="input3text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" maxlength="10">
                <input class="plannedcost" type="number" id="plannedinput3" onchange="updatePC()">
                <input class="actualcost" type="number" id="actualinput3" onchange ="updateAC()">
              </div>

              <!-- Input 3 -->
              <div class="inputfield">
                <input class="labelinput" type="text" id="input4text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" maxlength="10">
                <input class="plannedcost" type="number" id="plannedinput4" onchange="updatePC()">
                <input class="actualcost" type="number" id="actualinput4" onchange ="updateAC()">
              </div>

              <!-- Input 5 -->
              <div class="inputfield">
                <input class="labelinput" type="text" id="input5text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" maxlength="10">
                <input class="plannedcost" type="number" id="plannedinput5" onchange="updatePC()">
                <input class="actualcost" type="number" id="actualinput5" onchange ="updateAC()">
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
let labelData = loadLabelFromLocalStorage();
let plannedCostData = loadPCFromLocalStorage();
let actualCostData = loadACFromLocalStorage();
setUILabel(labelData);
setUIPCData(plannedCostData);
setUIACData(actualCostData);

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labelData,
    datasets: [{
      data: actualCostData,
      backgroundColor: "#2E9CCA",
    },{
      data: plannedCostData,
      backgroundColor: "#AAABB8",
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
          display: false,
        }
      },

    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0,
      }
    }
  }
});

// add label
function addLabel(chart, data) {
  chart.data.labels.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data = [...data]
  });
  chart.update();
  } 
  
  function updateLabel(event) {
      if (event) event.preventDefault();
      labelData = getUILabel();
      saveLabelToLocalStorage(labelData);
      addLabel(myChart, labelData);
  }
  
  //Updating chart with values
  function setUILabel(data) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.labelinput').forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
  }
  
  function getUILabel() {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.labelinput'))
        .map(el => String(el.value));
  }
  
  function saveLabelToLocalStorage(labelData) {
    localStorage.setItem('Label', JSON.stringify(labelData));
  }
  
  function loadLabelFromLocalStorage() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Label') || '[]');
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 //add "planned cost" data
 function addPC(chart, data) {
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
      dataset.data = [...data]
  });
  chart.update();
} 

//Calling input values to update chart
function updatePC(event) {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    plannedCostData = getUIPCData();
    savePCToLocalStorage(plannedCostData);
    addPC(myChart, plannedCostData);
}

//Updating chart with values
function setUIPCData(data) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.plannedcost').forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
}

function getUIPCData() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.plannedcost'))
      .map(el => Number(el.value));
}

function savePCToLocalStorage(plannedCostData) {
  localStorage.setItem('number2', JSON.stringify(plannedCostData));
}

function loadPCFromLocalStorage() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('number2') || '[]');
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//add actual cost 
 function addAC(chart, data) {
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
      dataset.data = [...data]
  });
  chart.update();
} 

//Calling input values to update chart
function updateAC(event) {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    actualCostData = getUIACData();
    saveACToLocalStorage(actualCostData);
    addAC(myChart, actualCostData);
}

//Updating chart with values
function setUIACData(data) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.actualcost').forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
}

function getUIACData() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.actualcost'))
      .map(el => Number(el.value));
}

function saveACToLocalStorage(actualCostData) {
  localStorage.setItem('number3', JSON.stringify(actualCostData));
}

function loadACFromLocalStorage() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('number3') || '[]');
}
```

```
body {
  background-color:#25274D;
}

.container {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.card {
  width: 57.5rem;
  height: 18rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.inputfield {
  display: flex;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0.65rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 0.5rem;
}

.inputs-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.65rem;
}

.chart-heading {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1.2rem 0 1.2rem 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: 100%;
}

.input-title {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8rem;
}

.plannedcost {
  width: 3.5rem;
}

.actualcost {
  width: 3.5rem;
}
```

I tried the code above but when increasing the value of the planned cost bar, the adjacent value actual cost bar increases as well.

Changing the label works perfectly but when increasing the values it doesn't work as intended. I assume it's because of the code below that is used for both the planned and actual cost but I'm not sure how to select what dataset to use for each bar.

```
function addBarData(chart, data) {
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data = [...data]
  });
  chart.update();
}
```

UPDATE

all charts work individually now but when they are on same page they start to glitch and share data.

```js
let stackedLabelData = loadLabelFromLocalStorage();
let plannedData = loadPlanedFromLocalStorage();
let startedData = loadStartedFromLocalStorage();
let completedData = loadCompletedFromLocalStorage();

setUILabel(stackedLabelData);
setPlannedUIData(plannedData);
setStartedUIData(startedData);
setCompletedUIData(completedData);

let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: stackedLabelData,
    datasets: [{
      data: plannedData,
      backgroundColor: "#AAABB8",
    },{
      data: startedData,
      backgroundColor: "#2E9CCA",
    },{
      data: completedData,
      backgroundColor: "#296484",
    }] 
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    plugins: {
      legend: {
          display: false,
        }
      },
      scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    },
  }
});

////////////////////////////////////// update labels ///////////////////////////////////

  function addBarLabel(chart, data) {
    chart.data.labels = data;
    chart.update();
  } 
  //Calling input values to update chart
  function updateLabel(event) {
      if (event) event.preventDefault();
      stackedLabelData = getUILabel();
      saveLabelToLocalStorage(stackedLabelData);
      addBarLabel(myChart, stackedLabelData);
  }
  
  //Updating chart with values
  function setUILabel(data) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.Labelinput').forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
  }
  
  function getUILabel() {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.Labelinput'))
        .map(el => String(el.value));
  }

  function saveLabelToLocalStorage(stackedLabelData) {
    localStorage.setItem('Label', JSON.stringify(stackedLabelData));
  }

  function loadLabelFromLocalStorage() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Label') || '[]');
  }

////////////////////////////////////// update planned ///////////////////////////////////

  function addBarData(chart, data, whichData) {
    const idx = {"planned":0,"started":1, "completed":2 }[whichData]
    chart.data.datasets[idx].data = data;
    chart.update();
  } 

  //Calling input values to update chart
  function updatePlanned(event) {
      if (event) event.preventDefault();
      plannedData = getPlannedUIData();
      savePlannedToLocalStorage(plannedData);
      addBarData(myChart, plannedData, "planned");
  }
  
  //Updating chart with values
  function setPlannedUIData(data) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.planned').forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
  }
  
  function getPlannedUIData() {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.planned'))
        .map(el => Number(el.value));
  }

  function savePlannedToLocalStorage(plannedData) {
    localStorage.setItem('plannedjobs', JSON.stringify(plannedData));
  }

  function loadPlanedFromLocalStorage() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('plannedjobs') || '[]');
  }
  
////////////////////////////////////// update started ///////////////////////////////////

  //Calling input values to update chart
  function updateStarted(event) {
      if (event) event.preventDefault();
      startedData = getStartedUIData();
      saveStartedToLocalStorage(startedData);
      addBarData(myChart, startedData, "started");
  }
  
  //Updating chart with values
  function setStartedUIData(data) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.started').forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
  }
  
  function getStartedUIData() {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.started'))
        .map(el => Number(el.value));
  }

  function saveStartedToLocalStorage(startedData) {
    localStorage.setItem('startedjobs', JSON.stringify(startedData));
  }

  function loadStartedFromLocalStorage() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('startedjobs') || '[]');
  }

////////////////////////////////////// update completed //////////////////////////////////
  //Calling input values to update chart
  function updateCompleted(event) {
      if (event) event.preventDefault();
      completedData = getCompletedUIData();
      saveCompletedFromLocalStorage(completedData);
      addBarData(myChart, completedData, "completed");
  }
  
  //Updating chart with values
  function setCompletedUIData(data) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.completed').forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
  }
  
  function getCompletedUIData() {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.completed'))
        .map(el => Number(el.value));
  }

  function saveCompletedFromLocalStorage(completedData) {
    localStorage.setItem('completedjobs', JSON.stringify(completedData));
  }

  function loadCompletedFromLocalStorage() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('completedjobs') || '[]');
  }
  
  
  

  ///////////////////////////////////Second file////////////////////////////////////////
  
  let labelData = loadLabelFromLocalStorage();
let plannedCostData = loadPCFromLocalStorage();
let actualCostData = loadACFromLocalStorage();

setUILabel(labelData);
setUIPCData(plannedCostData);
setUIACData(actualCostData);

ctx = document.getElementById('column');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labelData,
    datasets: [{
      data: actualCostData,
      backgroundColor: "#2E9CCA",
    },{
      data: plannedCostData,
      backgroundColor: "#AAABB8",
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
          display: false,
        }
      },

    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0,
      }
    }
  }
});

function addBarLabel(chart, data) {
  chart.data.labels = data;
  chart.update();
} 
  
  function updateLabel(event) {
      if (event) event.preventDefault();
      labelData = getUILabel();
      saveLabelToLocalStorage(labelData);
      addBarLabel(myChart, labelData);
  }
  
  //Updating chart with values
  function setUILabel(data) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.labelinput').forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
  }
  
  function getUILabel() {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.labelinput'))
        .map(el => String(el.value));
  }
  
  function saveLabelToLocalStorage(labelData) {
    localStorage.setItem('Label', JSON.stringify(labelData));
  }
  
  function loadLabelFromLocalStorage() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Label') || '[]');
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


function addBarData(chart, data, whichData) {
  const idx = whichData === "actual" ? 0:1;
  chart.data.datasets[idx].data = data;
  chart.update();
} 
  


//Calling input values to update chart
function updatePC(event) {
  if (event) event.preventDefault();
  plannedCostData = getUIPCData();
  savePCToLocalStorage(plannedCostData);
  addBarData(myChart, plannedCostData, "planned");
}

//Updating chart with values
function setUIPCData(data) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.plannedcost').forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
}

function getUIPCData() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.plannedcost'))
      .map(el => Number(el.value));
}

function savePCToLocalStorage(plannedCostData) {
  localStorage.setItem('number2', JSON.stringify(plannedCostData));
}

function loadPCFromLocalStorage() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('number2') || '[]');
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Calling input values to update chart
function updateAC(event) {
  if (event) event.preventDefault();
  actualCostData = getUIACData();
  saveACToLocalStorage(actualCostData);
  addBarData(myChart, actualCostData, "actual");
}


//Updating chart with values
function setUIACData(data) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.actualcost').forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
}

function getUIACData() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.actualcost'))
      .map(el => Number(el.value));
}

function saveACToLocalStorage(actualCostData) {
  localStorage.setItem('number3', JSON.stringify(actualCostData));
}

function loadACFromLocalStorage() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('number3') || '[]');
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:#25274D;
}

.container {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.card {
  width: 57.5rem;
  height: 18rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.inputfield {
  display: flex;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0.65rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 0.5rem;
}

.inputs-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.65rem;
}

.chart-heading {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1.2rem 0 1.2rem 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: 100%;
}

.input-title {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8rem;
}

.planned {
  width: 3.5rem;
}

.started {
  width: 3.5rem;
}

.completed {
  width: 3.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>WORKING INPUTS - Stacked bar</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="card">
    <p class="chart-heading">Job progress</p>

    <div class="container">
      
      <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>

        <div class="inputs-container">
          <div class="input-title">
            <p>Job</p>
            <p>Job progress(%)</p>
          </div>
              <!-- Input 1 -->
              <div class="inputfield">
                <input class="Labelinput" type="text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" value="Client 1" maxlength="10">
                <input class="planned" type="number" onchange ="updatePlanned()">
                <input class="started" type="number" onchange ="updateStarted()">
                <input class="completed" type="number" onchange ="updateCompleted()">
              </div>
              
              <!-- Input 2 -->
              <div class="inputfield">
                <input class="Labelinput" type="text" id="input2text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" value="Client 2" maxlength="10">
                <input class="planned" type="number" id="plannedinput2" onchange ="updatePlanned()">
                <input class="started" type="number" id="startedinput2" onchange ="updateStarted()">
                <input class="completed" type="number" id="completedinput2" onchange ="updateCompleted()">
              </div>

              <!-- Input 3 -->
              <div class="inputfield">
                <input class="Labelinput" type="text" id="input3text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" value="Client 3" maxlength="10">
                <input class="planned" type="number" id="plannedinput3" onchange ="updatePlanned()">
                <input class="started" type="number" id="startedinput3" onchange ="updateStarted()">
                <input class="completed" type="number" id="completedinput3" onchange ="updateCompleted()">
              </div>

              <!-- Input 3 -->
              <div class="inputfield">
                <input class="Labelinput" type="text" id="input4text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" value="Client 4" maxlength="10">
                <input class="planned" type="number" id="plannedinput4" onchange ="updatePlanned()">
                <input class="started" type="number" id="startedinput4" onchange ="updateStarted()">
                <input class="completed" type="number" id="completedinput4" onchange ="updateCompleted()">
              </div>

              <!-- Input 5 -->
              <div class="inputfield">
                <input class="Labelinput" type="text" id="input5text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" value="Client 5" maxlength="10">
                <input class="planned" type="number" id="plannedinput5" onchange ="updatePlanned()">
                <input class="started" type="number" id="startedinput5" onchange ="updateStarted()">
                <input class="completed" type="number" id="completedinput5" onchange ="updateCompleted()">
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>    


        <div class="card">
          <p class="chart-heading">Job progress</p>
      
          <div class="container">
            
            <div class="chart-container">
              <canvas id="column"></canvas>
            </div>
      
              <div class="inputs-container">
                <div class="input-title">
                  <p>Job</p>
                  <p>Job progress(%)</p>
                </div>
                    <!-- Input 1 -->
                    <div class="inputfield">
                      <input class="labelinput" type="text" id="input1text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" maxlength="10">
                      <input class="plannedcost" type="number" id="plannedinput1" oninput ="updatePC()">
                      <input class="actualcost" type="number" id="actualinput1" oninput ="updateAC()">
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Input 2 -->
                    <div class="inputfield">
                      <input class="labelinput" type="text" id="input2text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" maxlength="10">
                      <input class="plannedcost" type="number" id="plannedinput2" onchange="updatePC()">
                      <input class="actualcost" type="number" id="actualinput2" onchange ="updateAC()">
                    </div>
      
                    <!-- Input 3 -->
                    <div class="inputfield">
                      <input class="labelinput" type="text" id="input3text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" maxlength="10">
                      <input class="plannedcost" type="number" id="plannedinput3" onchange="updatePC()">
                      <input class="actualcost" type="number" id="actualinput3" onchange ="updateAC()">
                    </div>
      
                    <!-- Input 3 -->
                    <div class="inputfield">
                      <input class="labelinput" type="text" id="input4text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" maxlength="10">
                      <input class="plannedcost" type="number" id="plannedinput4" onchange="updatePC()">
                      <input class="actualcost" type="number" id="actualinput4" onchange ="updateAC()">
                    </div>
      
                    <!-- Input 5 -->
                    <div class="inputfield">
                      <input class="labelinput" type="text" id="input5text" onkeyup="updateLabel()" maxlength="10">
                      <input class="plannedcost" type="number" id="plannedinput5" onchange="updatePC()">
                      <input class="actualcost" type="number" id="actualinput5" onchange ="updateAC()">
                    </div>
      
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="stackedbar.js"></script>
    <script src="column.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does not work? If you mock the localStorage to return stuff, you can make a [mcve] here using the `[<>]` stacksnippet editor

Comment: Also just use one object and save it in one go

Comment: changing the label works prefect but when increasing the values it doesn't work as intended, I assume its because of the code below that is used for both the planned and actual cost but I'm not sure how to select what dataset to use for each bar.                                                                                                                                                  `function addAC(chart, data) {
  chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
      dataset.data = [...data]
  });
  chart.update();
}

Comment: Debug it. Does [...data] give you the expected values?

Comment: In local storage yes but not on the chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

Please consider being more DRY (don't repeat yourself) for example like this (incomplete) example

```js
// Configurations
const configs = {
  label: {
    localStorageKey: 'Label',
    querySelector: '.Labelinput',
    mapper: String,
  },
  planned: {
    localStorageKey: 'plannedjobs',
    querySelector: '.planned',
    mapper: Number,
  },
  started: {
    localStorageKey: 'startedjobs',
    querySelector: '.started',
    mapper: Number,
  },
  completed: {
    localStorageKey: 'completedjobs',
    querySelector: '.completed',
    mapper: Number,
  },
};

function loadFromLocalStorage(key) {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key) || '[]');
}

function saveToLocalStorage(key, data) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
}

function getUIData(querySelector, mapper) {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(querySelector)).map(el => mapper(el.value));
}

function setUIData(data, querySelector) {
  document.querySelectorAll(querySelector).forEach((el, i) => el.value = data[i] || '');
}

function addBarData(chart, data, whichData) {
  const idxMap = {
    "planned": 0,
    "started": 1,
    "completed": 2
  };
  chart.data.datasets[idxMap[whichData]].data = data;
  chart.update();
}

function update(event, type, chart) {
  if (event) event.preventDefault();
  const config = configs[type];
  const data = getUIData(config.querySelector, config.mapper);
  saveToLocalStorage(config.localStorageKey, data);
  addBarData(chart, data, type);
}

// Main script flow
const dataKeys = ['label', 'planned', 'started', 'completed'];
const data = dataKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = loadFromLocalStorage(configs[key].localStorageKey);
  setUIData(acc[key], configs[key].querySelector);
  return acc;
}, {});

let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // ... (unchanged chart configuration)
});

// Example of how to use the update function for "planned":
// function onSomeEventForPlanned(event) {
//   update(event, 'planned', myChart);
// }
```

Comment: yeah, I am relatively new to coding I've done a fair amount of hours on an html and css course and just a couple of hours on a javascript course so this project is really way out of my league but I'm understanding it more as I go, all the charts work perfectly individually my final step is just getting them all working on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect

```
function addBarData(chart, actualCostData, plannedCostData) {
  chart.data.datasets = [{ 
    data: actualCostData,
    backgroundColor: "#2E9CCA",
  },{
    data: plannedCostData,
    backgroundColor: "#AAABB8",
  }];
  chart.update();
}
```

to work better

Try this if you must

```
function addBarData(chart, data, whichData) {
  const idx = whichData === "actual" ? 0:1;
  chart.data.datasets[idx].data = data;
  chart.update();
} 

and 

function updateAC(event) {
  if (event) event.preventDefault();
  actualCostData = getUIACData();
  saveACToLocalStorage(actualCostData);
  addBarData(myChart, actualCostData, "actual");
}


function updatePC(event) {
  if (event) event.preventDefault();
  plannedCostData = getUIPCData();
  savePCToLocalStorage(plannedCostData);
  addBarData(myChart, plannedCostData, "planned");
}
```

Comment: I used the code and it worked! But I noticed that it worked only after refreshing the page, after refreshing the page it would display the right values so I changed chart.update(); to location.reload(); and it works now! Thank you!

Comment: No! That is not how it should work! There is something else going on if the update does not work. You are probably not getting both sets in one go then. No need to reload

Comment: See update. I just tried to stay DRY

Comment: Omg it works! thank you!!! this will be great for my project, something else if you don't mind. how could you do this for a chart with 3 datasets?

Comment: `const idx = {"actual":0,"planned":1, "cancelled":2 }[whichData]`

Comment: Awesome that worked as well, thank you so much!! I was stuck on that for so long, one final thing any idea why the label doesn't update until page is refreshed?

Comment: It doesn't? If not, then add the label in the script too

Comment: Awesome that worked as well! All errors are fixed now thank you so much!! part of my assessment, for top marks is getting help from an outside technologist so much appreciated :)

Comment: You are welcome. Hope it will be successful.

Comment: Sorry to open this up again but really struggling, see updated question, all charts work individually now but when on same page they start to share data, please help! *note the js is split into two files one for each chart, have added comment for when it spits